# Databinding to a Combobox, two List<object>, selected value should be copied AND shown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

**The Problem:**

Combobox shows no selected item on startup. To be exact: Item and Value are null, index is -1 and valuepath is empty. While the functionality of the binding itself seems to work, it simply refuses to show a value on startup.

**What I am trying to do:**

I have two lists of objects. ListOne is the full list of all available objects. 
ListTwo is a list of 21 "selected" objects out of the objects in list one.

So I want to bind ListOne to a combobox with the namevalue of the object to show. Meanwhile, the selected object should be bound to ListTwo[index].
Basically, if I change the selection in the combobox I want ListTwo[index] to be a copy of the now selected object.

**What I have right now:**

The Object in question:

```
public class Rezept
{
    public string strName { set; get; }
    public string strSomething { set; get; }
}
```

The XAML-Code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboboxName" ItemsSource="{Binding listOne}" SelectedValue="{Binding listTwo[0], Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="strName"/>
```

This seems to be working, as in selecting something updates ListTwo just fine. But on startup the combobox has nothing selected.

Another XAML-Code try:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboboxName" ItemsSource="{Binding listOne}" SelectedItem="{Binding listTwo[0], Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="strName"/>
```

This seems to behave exactly as the first, even tho it sounds more "correct".

Try three on the XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboboxName" ItemsSource="{Binding listOne}" SelectedItem="{Binding listTwo[0], Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="strName" SelectedValue="{Binding listTwo[0].strName}"/>
```

This changes nothing. Neither does binding to SelectedValuePath it seems.

What do i have to change so the combobox actually shows ListTwo[0] on startup? I did make sure ListTwo[0] actually has the right value. It does get populated by a xml file on startup tho, after the UI is loaded. Would this be a case of needing a "OnPropertyChanged"-Event somewhere? And if so, where? I am out of ideas otherwise.
Could still use a hand here tho :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since noone seems to have a solution (including myself after another 5 days of searching) I will at least post my VERY dirty workaround.

I made a List where I added every combobox in question via a loop (21 ones). Then I did another loop and manually set the Index of listOne in every Combobox to match the right value in listTwo. So it simply checks which index contains the right name and set it to that like this:

```
for(int i = 0, i < 21, i++)
{
    listCombo[i].SelectedIndex = listOne.IndexOf(listOne.Where(x => x.name == listTwo[i].name).First();
}
```

This only has to be called once one on startup of the programm, since listTwo actually has the right values in the right order (as seen in the XML save file as well).

Id still much rather find out how this is supposed to work in XAML Databinding tho. So if anyone has a real answer later on, feel free to poke me so i can update this one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding with `SelectedValue` property, you should have bind it with `SelectedItem` property like as follows:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboboxName" ItemsSource="{Binding listOne}" SelectedItem="{Binding listTwo[0], Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="strName"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this before (and did again after your comment). The result is exactly the same. The combobox has nothing selected this way. And i am out of ideas what to google really. Every guide i find suggests that it should just work like this. Is there something else that could cause this?